# How does Eval resolve to DataBinder.Eval?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to understand how the Eval() statement in ASPX/ASCX resolves to the `DataBinder.Eval(context, expression)` method, and more so where `Eval("Value")` goes to do it's Reflection before reaching this method?

I'm considering a couple of things that I'd like to do:

1. Introduce a similar thing to Eval - say `EvalList()` which justs dumps all the avaliable fields via Reflection that can be bound to, just to help when debugging/developing to determine what's avaliable on the context. I'd like to be able to just type `EvalList(`) rather than `SomeHelper.EvalList()`
2. Re-direct `Eval("")` to a different method, which will `Debug.Assert()` or similar to warn the developer if it's being over-used and that something else might be better for performance.

Comment: This is not directly addressing your questions, hence a comment and not an answer, but have you looked at model binding in ASP.NET WebForms 4.5? Read [ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Features - Strongly-Typed Data Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/03/26/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls.aspx) for a quick overview of how you may never need `Eval()` again.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: I think you deserve an upvote for the comment though!

Comment: @KarlAnderson: Actually I think you should add that as an answer. My problem is I don't know what I can bind to, I'm assuming if I use that technique I get intellisense so my problem is resolved. If I use that approach I also don't need reflection so the speed problem goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `Eval()` all together and use the model binding feature in ASP.NET WebForms 4.5 and later, like this:

Pre-ASP.NET 4.5 way using `Eval()`:

```
<asp:ListView ID="OrdersListView" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                            CommandName="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OrderID" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Eval("SalesOrderID") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Model binding way:

```
<asp:ListView ID="OrdersListView" runat="server" 
              ItemType="YourNamespace.YourClass">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" Text="Edit" 
                            CommandName="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="OrderID" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%#: Item.YourPropertyName %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Note: Because `ItemType` is strongly typed you will get IntelliSense help in Visual Studio as you type `Item.`.

Read [ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms Features - Strongly-Typed Data Controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/03/26/asp-net-4-5-web-forms-features-strongly-typed-data-controls.aspx) for a quick overview of how you may never need Eval() again.